# Find solution of Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the following Cauchy problem

$$y'=f(x,y), y(0)=\frac{1}{b}$$

Find an example of a function $f(x,y)$ such that the solution exists only on the interval $(-b,b)$ for $b>0$.

I thought to pick $y(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}$ since this is defined on $(-b,b)$.

Then differentiating we get $y'(x)=\frac{x}{(b^2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

So I thought to pick $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{(b^2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

Is my idea right?

In my notes there is the same example but for the interval $(-\sqrt{b}, \sqrt{b})$.

There the following is done:

$y'=g(x) y^2 , y(0)=a$ where $a=\frac{1}{b}$.

$\frac{dy}{y^2}=g(x) dx$

$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{a}-\int_0^x g(\xi) d \xi=\frac{1-a \int_0^x g(\xi) d \xi}{a}$

$y(x)=\frac{a}{1-a \int_0^x g(\xi) d \xi}$

$g(x)=2x$

$y(x)=\frac{1}{b-x^2}$

If we would also want to do it as in my notes, could we again look for a solution in the form $y'=g(x) y^2$ ?

Because I tried it and I got $y=\frac{1}{b-\int_0^x g(\xi) d \xi}$.

But can we get from this a solution that is defined on $(-b,b)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b$ should not be a part of $f$, since the task asks for all values of $1/b$.

But there is a very easy remedy by just eliminating the term with $b$:
$$
f(x,y)=xy^3
$$

Then you get
$$
y^{-2}= C-x^2
$$
and by the initial conditions $C=b^2$.

Comment: Then we get the same $y$ as I found, right?
$$$$
But in general how can we find $f$ ? If we would have an other interval, with what method could we find the appropriate $f$ ?

Comment: Yes, as the differential equation was constructed in both cases for the same function family. In general, you construct one function family satisfying the constraints that has one parameter and then eliminate the parameter from the equations for $y$ and $y'$.

Comment: Could you explain it further to ma? Maybe with an aother example?